# Get custom AppSettings Section from ASP.NET Web.Config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have the following custom app-settings style config section

```
<configSections>
   <sectionGroup name="Fruits">
      <section name="Colors" />
   </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<Fruits>
   <add key="apple" value="red" />
   <add key="banana" value="yellow" />
</Fruits>
```

I am trying to use the following code to fetch the color of the `apple`

```
    var settingsCollection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Fruits/Colors") as AppSettingsSection;
    if (settingsCollection != null)
    {
        var color= settingsCollection.Settings["apple"];
    }
```

The above code does not work because `settingsCollection` does not get any object assigned to it because it is not cast-able to AppSettingsSection.

When I put the following in the Watch window, I see the type as `KeyValueInternalCollection`

> ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Fruits/Colors") as AppSettingsSection

What am I missing? I am inside my web app, so I assume I don't have to use `OpenExeConfiguration`, and I don't no such method as `ConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration` as I found on some forums.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this snippet.

```
NameValueCollection Fruits = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Fruits");

foreach (string key in Fruits.Keys)
{
    string[] values = Fruits.GetValues(key);
    foreach (string value in values)
    {
         Label1.Text += key + " - " + value + "<br>";
    }
}
```